# Weblogic server not running from jdeveloper

Tags: java, websphere, weblogic, jdeveloper

When i tried to run an application on jdeveloper, the server wont start and it shows the following message

```
*** Using HTTP port 7101 ***

*** Using SSL port 7102 ***
C:\Users\Ayodeji.Ayodeji\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.2.3.39.62.76.1\DefaultDomain\bin\startWebLogic.cmd

[waiting for the server to complete its initialization...]

\IBM\WebSphere was unexpected at this time.

Process exited.
```

Answer (score 3):

Finally i got the problem solved. I tried to locate the startWebLogic.cmd file in the specified path, and went through the file, then i realise its trying to access my classpath, so on checking my classpath from the environment variables, its has only entries to Websphere so i deleted the entry, restarted JDeveloper and my server is up and running.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Eclipse setting Weblogic, I was trying to start the Server, but got the same error.
\IBM\WebSphere was unexpected at this time.

It was due to Window 7 folder security issue. As soon as I realized that, I close eclipse and start eclipse with Administration Right. That resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

1.Go to

> C:\Users\Ayodeji.Ayodeji\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\

Ayodeji.Ayodeji should be your PC User name

2. then change

> system11.1.2.3.39.62.76.1

Folder name to another name and run.